# Plotting intersection of triaxial ellipsoid with a plane in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry, computational-geometry, ellipse

What's the best way to plot the intersection of a randomly oriented triaxial ellipsoid with a plane in polar coordinates? The plane runs over a range of longitudes at a given latitude.

The code below should plot the intersection of an array of spheres with a plane with latitude plane_lat. (A sphere has center coordinates: sphere_x,sphere_y,sphere_z; distance away from origin: sphere_dist; and spherical radius: sphere_rad.)

```
for i in range(len(hole_rad)):
    deltaz = (sphere_dist[i]*np.cos(sphere_lat[i]*degtorad))*np.tan(plane_lat*degtorad)-sphere_dist[i]*np.sin(sphere_lat[i]*degtorad)
    if np.abs(deltaz)<sphere_radius[i]:
        rprime = sphere_rad[i]*np.sin(np.arccos(abs(deltaz)/(sphere_rad[i])));
        x = rprime * np.sin(newtheta)+sphere_x[i]*H0
        y = rprime * np.cos(newtheta)+sphere_y[i]*H0
        z = np.zeros(np.shape(newtheta))
        cr,clat,clon=ACD.cartesian_to_spherical(x,y,z)
        circles=ax.plot(np.rad2deg(clon),cr,c='blue',linewidth=0.1)
```

This was my roundabout attempt using python/matplotlib. There's got to be a better way of accomplishing this.
Any ideas on how to do this for ellipsoids (preferably in python)?